# This python FTP program throws strange exception

Tags: python, ftp, urllib

I have this very simple Python program that works:

```py
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('ftp.unicamp.br')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('pub/libreoffice/flatpak/latest/')
```

But if I remove the trailing slash from that path, I get this exception:

```py
ftp.cwd('pub/libreoffice/flatpak/latest') # no trailing slash

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "foo.py", line 6, in <module>
#     ftp.cwd('pub/libreoffice/flatpak/latest')
#   File "/home/ian/.asdf/installs/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 631, in cwd
#     return self.voidcmd(cmd)
#   File "/home/ian/.asdf/installs/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 278, in voidcmd
#     return self.voidresp()
#   File "/home/ian/.asdf/installs/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 251, in voidresp
#     resp = self.getresp()
#   File "/home/ian/.asdf/installs/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 246, in getresp
#     raise error_perm(resp)
# ftplib.error_perm: 550 pub/libreoffice/flatpak/latest: No such file or directory
```

The problem is I'm using `urllib` like so:

```py
import urllib.request
fp = urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/libreoffice/flatpak/latest/LibreOffice.flatpak')
```

And `urllib` doesn't include the last trailing slash, thus giving the same exception as shown above. Any hints on how I could force `urllib` to include the trailing slash in the path?

Comment: tried using `requests` instead of `urllib`?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the server. Same happens with `pub/libreoffice` vs. `pub/libreoffice/`. Even doing a `cwd pub` and then `cwd libreoffice` will not work, only `cwd libreoffice/`. But `cwd pub` is fine, no `cwd pub/` is needed. And `cwd pub/apache` will work too, no `cwd pub/apache/` needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have libreoffice folder inside pub?

if you navavigate and check the folders inside pub you will see:

```
ftp.cwd('/pub')
#'250 CWD command successful'

ftp.nlst()
#<class 'list'>: ['GCNET', 'apache', 'apoio', 'banespa', 'biglinux', 'broffice', 'centos', 'ctmq', 'debian', 'downsizing', 'postgresql', 'ppc64el', 'security', 'suporte2', 'FreeBSD', 'deepines', 'gian', 'suporte', 'tdf', 'unix-tools', 'msg.welcome']
```